# How to decode html string from windows-1252 using python 3

Tags: html, python-3.x, character-encoding, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some web page contents (web scraping) using python 3. I have met with one html web page with the following sample string;

```
<!sh6dnzerw9bef91nf0n2p6drlmxdadeulbyz24ho3kt kkoqb3jrzn b1xg21mndpb4h7cw0og1zrffu9qbz5b2w09psl3x16r 3uwu93myls56s>
```

I used the following statements to identify the format and decode correspondingly;

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='xxxxxx'
webpage=requests.get(url, verify=False)
soup= BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, 'html.parser')

if soup.original_encoding=='utf-8':
    content=str(webpage.content, 'utf-8')
if soup.original_encoding=='cp1252':
    content=str(webpage.content, 'cp1252')
if soup.original_encoding=='windows-1252':
    content=str(webpage.content, 'windows-1252')
if soup.original_encoding=='ISO-8859-1':
    content=str(webpage.content, 'ISO-8859-1')

print(content)
```

If I print "soup.original_encoding", it returns "windows-1252". However, the statement "print(content)" displays the web page in the same encoded format (as of the sample string above). Please, any suggestion on how I can do the conversion to the readable format.

Comment: Note: you could write with `elif`, or better with a `for`.

Comment: The string would be the same regardless of interpreting or misinterpreting using any of the character encodings you listed. The issue is something else. Please [edit] your question. What is the content you expect? How does it look in a web browser?

Comment: @Tom...on the browser, the page just displays email and password text fields. In the source view, you can only view encoded strings as html and script statements. My intention is to decode and look for the existence of particulars tags (e.g form, input etc) and words (e.g log in, sign in etc)

Answer (score 1):

You did correctly.

All the encodings on your code share the ASCII printable characters (and code). As you see, you have `<` and `>` correct, and then just identifiers.

So the original page is not HTML, or it includes non HTML part, which could be decoded by a javascript, this is often done to obfuscate the data or the code, just to prevent what you are doing.  You may need to read the site TOS and respect the will of site owner.

Comment: Yes @Giacomo Catenazzi, the web page is a malicious one so it is obfuscated with html escape characters as well, which I was able to decode. Its header's content type returns "text/html" which means it is a html page. The application I am developing is supposed to decode the complete web page. The web page contains many of such formatted tags